# Swift: My Convenience init does not see the normal init

Tags: ios, swift, init

I am trying to create a convenience init for my class: User. I've done this before for another class, and - to create it again - I have used the same code, just differed for my User class.

Here is my User class:

```
import Foundation

class User {
    //Database Variables
    let userID: String?
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let password: String?
    let emailID: String?
    let dob: String? //timestamp
    let picture: String? //URL?
    let location: Location?
    let sex: String?

    convenience init(data: [[String: AnyObject]]) {
        self.init(userID: String(data["user_id"]!),
            firstName: String(data["first_name"]!),
            lastName: String(data["last_name"]!),
            password: String(data["password"]!),
            emailID: String(data["email"]!),
            dob: String(data["dob"]!),
            picture: String(data["picture"]!),
            location: Location(
                String(data["street"]!),
                String(data["city"]!),
                String(data["state"]!),
                String(data["zip"]!),
                String(data["country"]!)),
            sex: String(data["sex"]!))
    }

    init (userID: String, firstName: String, lastName: String,
          password: String, emailID: String, dob: String,
          picture: String, location: Location, sex: String) {
        self.userID = userID
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.password = password
        self.emailID = emailID
        self.dob = dob
        self.picture = picture
        self.location = location
        self.sex = sex
    }
```

However, Swift doesn't see the self.init method. I am getting a `Could not find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments`

What is wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are calling the init with some extra parameters: city, state, zip...

Comment: Right, but those are all part of the Location object

Comment: It seems like you have error in your Location initializer, can you post the code for init method in Location class.

Comment: Here: init(streetAddress: String, city: String, state: String, zipCode: String, countryCode: String)

Comment: The error messages refers to the `Location(...)` call because the parameter names are missing: `Location(streetAddress: ..., city: ..., ...)`.

Comment: I tried doing that, I still get the same error

Comment: But I had different capitalization for zipCode. Thank you! It works now. Post an answer and I'll select it

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant: That is very kind, but only the author of the question can accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the convenience `init` an Array of `Dictionary [[String : AnyObject]]`
Did you mean to pass just a `Dictionary: [String : AnyObject]` ?

Comment: Yes I did. However, even with that change, the code doesn't compile

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Peter said about the array of dictionaries,
the creation of the Location object

```
Location(String(data["street"]!), String(data["city"]!), String(data["state"]!), String(data["zip"]!)
```

is wrong because the parameter names are missing.
Assuming from your other code that this is *Swift 2*, it should be

```
Location(streetAddress: String(data["street"]!), city: String(data["city"]!), state: String(data["state"]!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit Enter after self.init(...) in convenience init. It will remove the error if the parameters are correct.

Comment: It didn't work. If I try to get Xcode to autocomplete the argument for `self.init(` it just writes `self`

Comment: It was weird and it was not able to autocomplete the call. But it removed the error I was getting when I wrote down the entire init call and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

In first place, I think your declaration is wrong, you declared an array of array when you should only declare a normal array.

Wrong:

```
convenience init(data: [[String: AnyObject]])
```

Correct:

```
convenience init(data: [String: AnyObject])
```

After, you must pass the parameter like that:

```
self.init(userID: (data["user_id"] as! String).....
```

I hope I've helped you :)